# What is the meaning of these square brackets in my R code for model selection?

Tags: r, model, subset, kable

I am going through some code someone sent me and I am trying to make sense of it. They built a series of models, used AIC to compare them, and then kable to visualize them. The problem is I don't know if or why they subsetted these models and what the square brackets in the code below mean:

```
m0 = glmer(y~x,data=data)
m1 = glmer(y~x+z,data=data)
m2-m14 = glmer...etc

models_rank_AICc = model.sel(m0,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12,m13,m14, rank=AICc)
models_rank_sub = models_rank_AICc[c(1:14),-c(2:10)]
models_rank_sub$weight = round(models_rank_sub$weight,3)
kable(models_rank_sub)
```

So my question is what does the -c(2:10) mean? The kable displays a table of all 15 models, it doesn't somehow leave out models 2 through 10

Answer (score 0):

That expression is leaving out *columns* 2 through 10; see `?"["` for (somewhat terse) documentation. `x[i,j]` indexes rows `i` and columns `j` of a rectangular object (data frame/matrix/whatever), negative values drop elements.

Comment: Aha that explains it. The kable has a whole bunch of columns of the predictor coefficients which we don't need to look at. You answered the question perfectly

Comment: if this solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...